# How to download some text content as a .ftl file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have some text content, getting from one api call. On a button click I want to download that text content as a .ftl file. I have used  **"data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,"**, but after using this I am  getting downloaded file as .txt. I want to download as a .ftl file.

Comment: how are you downloading a file? Please add your sample code here.

Comment: try this small js [library](http://danml.com/download.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a form with a function call:

```
<form onsubmit="download('file.ftl', [your.data])">
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

The download function:

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Why to even show an input tag and on click of it, create an anchor element. Just use the anchor element itself directly instead of input!